# Androidx Navigation IllegalStateException after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, androidx

I have an app using AndroidX's Navigation library, but I'm getting odd behavior. Particularly around my app going in/out of the background. Here are two examples:

1. In a simple on click listener in a Fragment I have:

(Kotlin)

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    findNavController().popBackStack()
}
```

From this, I see crashes saying it threw an `IllegalStateException` since it ran after `onSaveInstanceState`.

2. I have a `ViewModel` associated with my `Fragment` and I register my observers to the fragment view's lifecycle. This means that I get notified during `onStart`. Some key events, such as login state determine the app's navigation. In my case I have a splash screen that could go to either a login screen or the main screen. Once a user completes login, I reset the navigation (taking me back to the splash screen). Now the auth state is ready and I want to navigate to the main fragment, this throws an error often because `onResume` must be called before the `FragmentManager` is considered ready. I get an error saying I'm in the middle of a transaction and I can't add a new one. To mediate this I had to write this strange bit of code:

(Kotlin)

```
private fun safeNavigateToMain() {
    if (fragmentManager == null) {
      return
    }
    if (!isResumed) {
        view?.post { safeNavigateToMain() }
        return
    }
    try {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.main)
    } catch (tr: Throwable) {
        view?.post { safeNavigateToMain() }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can get the navigation controller to play nice with the fragment lifecycles without having to add these workarounds?

Comment: What version of Navigation are you using?

Comment: 1.0.0-alpha02 for the fragment and ui, and 1.0.0-alpha01 for the plugin during the crashes, updated to 02 recently but that build hasn't hit production yet so I don't have any stack traces yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Navigation 1.0.0-alpha03 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes#july_12_2018):

> FragmentNavigator now ignores navigation operations after FragmentManager has saved state, avoiding “Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState” exceptions [b/110987825](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110987825)

So upgrading to alpha03 should remove this error.

Comment: Is it possible to use `commitAllowingStateLoss` with Navigation Component?

Comment: @bitvale - no. You shouldn't be losing state at all.